# azure service bus: what is the ideal number of `MaxConcurrentCalls`

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus

As per docs using Azure Service Bus `MaxConcurrentCalls` feature, we can specify how many messages we want to process concurrently.

My question is what is the ideal number of `MaxConcurrentCalls`? I am processing service bus message in a web api application which is running and hosted over cloud VM.

```
var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 5,
            AutoComplete = false
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no ideal number. There's a default number the property is set to that offers a safe performance for the most use cases. When you want to optimize that number, you'd need to look at the average duration of your message processing, CPU/memory/IOPS where the processor runs. You'd need to look at the number of pre-fetched messages. Potentially adjust message lock duration. Benchmark and identify the optimal concurrency for your scenario and workload.

Additional good resource to review would be the [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#development-and-testing-features) article.